# Why magenta colored methods name in class browser method panel?

Tags: dolphin-smalltalk

Why do some method have their name colored in magenta in the class browser method panel ?

Answer (score 0):

Magenta color methods are loose methods.

A "loose method" is a method that belong a package different from the package of it's class.

If you have ClassB in PackageB. And at the same time there are some methods in ClassB that belong to PackageC these methods are "loose".

To move a method to a package is simple drag and drop.